# Insecure MAC built on pseudorandom function

Tags: cryptanalysis, mac, pseudo-random-function

this is a question about Katz-Lindell book, introduction to modern cryptography, 2nd edition, exercise 4.7, part c.
[image]

For (a) and (b) it is clear that the Macs are insecure, but for (c) I am struggling to see why.

For me, when the attacker will present his pair $(m^*, \langle r^*,t^* \rangle)$, the MAC will sample uniformly its own $r$ (before applying the $\operatorname{Vrfyk}(.)$ algorithm), and will prepend $r$ to the computed $t$.

So no matter how the attacker will choose $m^*$ (even if the attacker chooses $m^*$ randomly), the MAC (assuming that it is a deterministic MAC using a canonical verification) will always sample a random $r$ from ${0,1}^n$, independently from the one $(r^*)$ that the attacker output to it, and the probability that $r=r^*$ will be negligible. So it is still secure MAC, the one presented in part (c).

Can someone correct me if I am wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

> assuming that it is a deterministic MAC using a canonical verification

It is not, randomness is involved in the tag generation, therefore it is not *deterministic* and cannot use canonical verification.

This then means that an attacker doesn't have to follow the MAC algorithm but instead has to find $m',(r',t')$ such that verification suceeds, picking $t'=0$ is a good starting point for that.